# Use variable to find documents in collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to find the largest value of a specific field `fieldName` in a mongo collection.
For this purpose I created a helper `largestValue`:

```
UI.registerHelper('largestValue', function(fieldName) {
  return Collection.findOne({fieldName: {$exists: true}}, {sort: {fieldName: -1}}).value;
```

However, this always returns as undefined. If I use the actual field name instead of the `fieldName` parameter in the return statement, a document is returned.

How can I use parameters for this purpose?

The function is called in HTML like this: `largest value of X: {{largestValue 'X'}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{fieldName: -1}` will create an object with the key `fieldName` storing the value `-1`. To achieve what you want, you need to create a variable and use the square bracket syntax:

```js
var object = {}
object[fieldName] = -1
```

And then use `object` instead of `{fieldName: -1}`. So, the following should work in your case:

```js
UI.registerHelper('largestValue', function(fieldName) {
   var where = {}
   where[fieldName] = {$exists: true}
   var sort = {}
   sort[fieldName] = -1
   return Collection.findOne(where, {sort: sort}).value;
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to figure how to use your suggestion within my example, e.g. how can I rewrite my return statement to include your suggestion?

Comment: @user3809275, See my answer again.

Comment: @PeppeL-G You should probably update your answer to also handle the query object that also uses `fieldname`.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, Good catch, I didn't see it was used in multiple places.

Comment: Your answer helped me to get there. I also added a var for the fields I wanted to return (since I only need one). To get the actual value I had to use a switch expression on `fieldName`, e.g. if the case was `valueA` it returns `Collection.findOne(where, {sort: sort}, {fields: fields}).valueA`.